# Creating jvectormap in React

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, dom, jvectormap

So I am trying to insert a map from jvectormap for a web application. 
Here is my code for northAmerica.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {Link} from 'react-router'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import $ from 'jquery';


class NorthAmerica extends Component{
    componentDidMount() {
        const el = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.display);
        $(el).vectorMap({map: 'world_mill'});
    }


    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <button id="back"><Link to="/discover" style={{display: 'block', height: '100%'}}></Link></button>
                <h1>NORTH AMERICA MAP PLACE-HOLDER</h1>
                <div ref={display => this.display = display} style={{width: '600px', height: '400px'}}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export class northAmerica extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(<NorthAmerica/>);
    }
}
```

northAmerica.js is a sub-menu page that will be passed to a page index.js to render to the DOM.

index.gsp is the html page where index.js exports to.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
        <title>Food App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="${resource(dir: 'css', file: 'text.css')}" type = "text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="${resource(dir: 'css', file: 'jquery-jvectormap-2.0.3.css')}" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
    <script src="jquery-jvectormap-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-jvectormap-world-mill.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="root" align="left"></div>
<br/>
<asset:javascript src="bundle.js"/>
</body>
</html>
```

The web app navigates to this "North America" page however there is no map.

Is there something in my code that is off or could it be the placement of my files?

Comment: can you inspect the html to see whether it renders anything?

Comment: OH no, it does. It renders everything fine. Even the North America page, just not the map itself

Comment: can you add the script dynamically? it might because on page load the element is not there and then react renders it.server side rendering might help as well